# Android - Accessing Other Class's Objects (Java)

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a game it has more than 10 levels, all contains same "CheckWin()" method and that too long and does many stuffs like changing values, updating scores, updating time, changing images and all, so I want to move that "CheckWin()" method to a new Class named "Functions", so the main problem the method needs to access some Views, Values, Objects etc... and change some views in the class that invoked this method, right now I'm doing it like

```
//In Level Activity Calling The Method
    ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Function function = new Funtions();

//And In Functions Class Changing Images

    public void CheckWin() {
        Level1.imageView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Level2.imageView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Level3.imageView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Level4.imageView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Level5.imageView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Level6.imageView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Level7.imageView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Level8.imageView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Level9.imageView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Level10.imageView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

but this gives an error, so how can I check on which level the user is and which class called this Method so I can use only one statement to do all this... like

```
    public void CheckWin() {
        ClassThatInvokedThisMethod.imageView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use abstraction please.

Make a baseclass with the given functionality and extend it in your levels
You can make an implementation in `BaseLevel` if all are exactly the same, otherwise override it in your `Level1` class

```
public class Level1 extends BaseLevel{
 ...
    // if implementation is different per class
    public void checkwin(){

    }
}

public abstract class BaseLevel extends AppCompatActivity{

    public abstract void checkwin();
}
```

Or likes this

```
public class Level1 extends BaseLevel{
 ...
    // if implementation is always the same

}

public abstract class BaseLevel extends AppCompatActivity{

    public void checkwin(){
        // do it here
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please give and example? I don't understand what to actually do :|

Comment: But My Class Is Already Extending To An Activity It Shows An Error "Class Cannot Extend Multiple Classes"

Comment: See updated code, extend your baselevel to the activity